# Fixed Static Cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

[image: https://puu.sh/cnc93/70bd9c423f.png]

In my iPad application, I have used a UICollectionView which displays different notes saved by the user in core data through NSFetchedResultsController.
According to the design, I must have to show a cell with control to add new note in core data. Once the note is added it is displayed as the 2nd cell in the collection view.

I tried to implement it in following manner;

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView
{
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections.count?:1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:   (NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]?:1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.item == 0)
{
    AddNewNoteCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AddNewNoteCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.delegate = self;
    return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        NoteCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"NoteCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        //Code for customization
    return cell;
   }
}
```

But this approach is causing problems. It doesn't add the newly created note cell immediately. If it adds, the newly added cell is displayed as "Add new cell". If I pop the view controller and load the view controller again it displays the cells correctly.

Please guide me for an accurate solution.
Is this possible?

Comment: "is causing problems".. You expect people to figure out what the problems are ? Please edit your question to provide more details..

Comment: @rdurand edited! Please figure it out now!

Comment: Please increase the rating so that I could get a reply...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the "add new note" cell to appear as the first item in the first section, but not in any other sections, you need to modify your `numberOfItemsInSection` method to add 1 to the `[sectionInfo numberOfObjects]` for section 0.  For the other sections, you should just return the `numberOfObjects`:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:   (NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    NSInteger items = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    if (section == 0) items++;
    return items; 
}
```

Then in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` you can (as you have) treat item 0 in section 0 as your special case (i.e. give it a different cell subclass and configure it accordingly).  For the other cells, you can configure them using the `indexPath` to get details from your `fetchedResultsController`.  However, in section 0, you need to adjust this: cell 0 is your "Add new note" cell, so you want cell 1 to be configured with the details of item 0 from your `fetchedResultsController`.  Construct a new indexPath:

```
NSIndexPath *fetchIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:(indexPath.row -1) inSection:0];
```

and use that to get the correct data from your fetchedResultsController.

I assume your "Add new note" cell calls some method in your view controller to add the new note object to your `managedObjectContext`.  If you implement the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods (see [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html)), you can immediately update your collectionView with the newly added object.  But you must reverse the above adjustment for section 0:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.collectionView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{ 
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.collectionView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.collectionView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *adjustedIndexPath;
    NSIndexPath *adjustedNewIndexPath;
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        adjustedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:(indexPath.row+1) inSection:0];
        adjustedNewIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:(newIndexPath.row+1) inSection:0];
        indexPath = adjustedIndexPath;
        newIndexPath = adjustedNewIndexPath;
    }
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:newIndexPath];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.collectionView endUpdates];
}
```

You should tailor the above methods to suit your particular needs (eg. I assume you don't want to permit a section to be moved ahead of section 0).

Comment: is "[self.collectionView beginUpdates];" your own subclassed method? collection view doesn't have such method by default.

Comment: @HashmatKhalil No, my mistake, I was hacking table view code.